# How can you access your online postgresql database when developing on your local machine?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I want to start developing a django app on heroku which uses the postgresql database. I already got my hello world django app working on heroku, but now I am wondering how to develop with the postgresql database.

How do people do this? Can I link to the heroku postgresql database in the settings.py and develop on my local 'django runserver' server?

How do people do this? Do they use a postgresql database on their own machine? How would you keep the online one and your local one the same?

Comment: Do you really want to do development on your production database? It's not an awesome idea. If not, just install the database system on your dev server it will be simpler. Alternatively if your database exposes a port (if running Linux use netstat -ntpl to figure that out) you can use it from your dev server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the best way - it is to copy database to your local machine, but it will be hard, if you have got huge database.

You can also use working database from remote server. Just type ip/host and other settings for database on your server and you'll get access.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about python and how you interact with heroku (do you use the heroku cli??) but in the Ruby land we can do `heroku db:pull` which will pull the DB from heroku and magically transpose it into whatever DB you use locally, the same for pushes. It also supports individual/combintations of tables to push/pull.

Comment: You should not be using `heroku db:pull` as this is specific to rails and uses taps which has many gotchas. Instead you should be doing an actual database dump and restore. You can do this with `heroku pgbackups:capture` and `heroku pgbackups:restore`